# Reporting Services Expression use data from other cells

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

In this table, i'm trying to calculate the following :

- percentage of men over all "représentant" in the "représentant"->Men row
- percentage of women over all "représentant" in the "représentant"->Women row

I manage to get Gender Total by sum. Now i'd like to use the result in an expression in men and woman row. Is that possible ?

If that is possible, i'd like to hide the gender total row ( I just need it for calculation)

If not, are there any other possibilities to get these percentages ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ReportItems!TextboxName.Value for this.  If you name your textbox for Women WomenTotal, you can refer to it using ReportItems!WomenTotal.Value.

This is the easiest way to refer to any particular cell value in SSRS.